# Why can I only insert a value once for each columnID

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting data to my db using this:

```
$insertPlayerFix = "INSERT INTO playerfixtures (fixture_id, player_id, goals_scored) VALUE (?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($insertPlayerFix);
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $fixtureFix_ID,$playerFix_ID,$goalsScored);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
```

This works fine until I have data for each of the `fixtureID`'s. It then seemingly inserts data and gives me the success message but nothing new is stored.

It is like I am telling it to check for `fixtureID` and if > 0 to not do anything(which I am not, obviously).

Comment: So what are your types for fixture_id, player_id and goals_scored?... You are assuming they are strings in your bind_param statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be you have an autoincrement column for fixture_id

in this case you should not use this column in you insert clause

eg:

```
$insertPlayerFix = "INSERT INTO playerfixtures ( player_id, goals_scored) VALUE (?,?)";

$insertPlayerFix = "INSERT INTO playerfixtures ( player_id, goals_scored) VALUE (?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($insertPlayerFix);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $fixtureFix_ID,$playerFix_ID,$goalsScored);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
```

and id normally are integer so check for the correct data type and eventually modify  you binding

Comment: I can't believe I did not see that. Thank you. I will accept as soon as I can.